# Retrieve Data from AWS RDS (MSSQL) using AWS Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm searching the internet for a comprehensive step by step tutorial regarding this topic and I can't seem to find one. The docs provided by AWS are a bit vague. Can you guys recommend a site, article or a tutorial? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To access RDS, you need to place your Lambda function in a subnet inside a VPC since its not recommended to deploy RDS instance in a public subnet which is accessible through internet. You also needs to make sure you Lambda function can access the RDS instance via the network by configuring Security groups assigned to the Lambda function appropriately.

Go through tutorial: [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Amazon RDS in an Amazon VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html)for more details.